# How to dynamically generate schema for cube.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cube.js

I have been working on a project to generate configurable dashboards.
so i have to generate schema dynamically based on an api request. is there any way to do that?

it will be very helpful if there is any working example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an `asyncModule` function for this scenario. You can check example below:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Funnels = require('Funnels');

asyncModule(async () => {
  const funnels = await (await fetch('http://your-api-endpoint/funnels')).json();

  class Funnel {
    constructor({ title, steps }) {
      this.title = title;
      this.steps = steps;
    }

    get transformedSteps() {
      return Object.keys(this.steps).map((key, index) => {
        const value = this.steps[key];
        let where = null
        if (value[0] === PAGE_VIEW_EVENT) {
          if (value.length === 1) {
            where = `event = '${value[0]}'`
          } else {
            where = `event = '${value[0]}' AND page_title = '${value[1]}'`
          }
        } else {
          where = `event = 'se' AND se_category = '${value[0]}' AND se_action = '${value[1]}'`
        }

        return {
          name: key,
          eventsView: {
            sql: () => `select * from (${eventsSQl}) WHERE ${where}`
          },
          timeToConvert: index > 0 ? '30 day' : null
        }
      });
    }

    get config() {
      return {
        userId: {
          sql: () => `user_id`
        },
        time: {
          sql: () => `time`
        },
        steps: this.transformedSteps
      }
    }
  }

  funnels.forEach((funnel) => {
    const funnelObject = new Funnel(funnel);
    cube(funnelObject.title, {
      extends: Funnels.eventFunnel(funnelObject.config),
      preAggregations: {
        main: {
          type: `originalSql`,
        }
      }
    });
  });
})
```

More info: https://cube.dev/docs/schema-execution-environment#async-module

Comment: Can this be dynamic, on a per quest basis? I want to be able to update the schema on the fly and my (limited) understanding of this code is that will not be supported.

Comment: @oden It actually can. Please check https://cube.dev/docs/multitenancy-setup#multiple-schema-and-drivers for that. You can have one schema per tenant. And tenants can as granular as you want it to be.