# On The Fly Dynamic Schemas

Tags: cube.js

I am looking through [Dynamic Cube Creation](https://cube.dev/docs/schema/advanced/dynamic-schema-creation) and was wondering - is there a way to get a cube created post Cube process startup?

In this use case, we have multiple schemas being created on the fly as users navigate through a front end app, and, will need to have some cubes created when those schemas are created. Initially, the search began for a Cube endpoint to allow the creation of cubes, but, it doesn't seem to be out there.

I have seen this question: [How to dynamically generate schema for cube.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213264/how-to-dynamically-generate-schema-for-cube-js), but, I don't see how it could work for the above use case, and, in the selected answer, there is a mention of a tenant-by-tenant basis, which, we are not in need of.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to trigger an update on the compilation of schemas. Take a look at [Schema Versioning](https://cube.dev/docs/schema/advanced/dynamic-schema-creation#usage-with-schema-version).

```js
module.exports = {
  schemaVersion: async ({ securityContext }) => {
    const schemaVersions = await (
      await fetch('http://your-api-endpoint/schemaVersion')
    ).json();

    return schemaVersions['version'];
  },
};
```

Basically, you need to do a version increment every time the underlying data schema has changed. I modified the example from the docs removing multitenancy just to show how you would have to create the response from your API.